# linq to update value in database view

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

I am working as a selenium automation tester. I tried adding the table to datamodel in visual 2013, since the table has hierarchy, it has thrown error. So, I found a work around to use view. Now I need to update a value in view using sql. I used

```
var acct = context.Regression_TestAccounts.Where(f => f.Account_ID.Equals(acctId))
                                          .FirstOrDefault();

acct.AvailableDailyCreditLimit_Amt = acct.ApprovedDailyCreditLimit_Amt;
acct.AvailableTotalCreditLimit_Amt = acct.ApprovedTotalCreditLimit_Amt;
```

This is not making any changes to the values.Could some one help me with this.

Comment: Are you calling `context.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a lot of code that you are missing. This is not a Selenium issue. It's an "I don't know Entity Framework" issue. First, you have to call [SaveChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx) to be able to persist any updates in your objects. Also, it is recommended to use [Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can revert any possible problems during your update. Also, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) is an article on how to add/attach entity states. This way you can update the object.

```
public void Update(int acctId)
{
    using(var context = new Context())
    {
        using(var dbContextTransaction = new context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                //improved query
                var acct = context.Regression_TestAccounts
                                  .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Account_ID == acctId);   

                if(acct == null) //don't just return, tell the user there was no update
                    return;  

                acct.AvailableDailyCreditLimit_Amt = acct.ApprovedDailyCreditLimit_Amt;
                acct.AvailableTotalCreditLimit_Amt = acct.ApprovedTotalCreditLimit_Amt;

                context.Entry(acct).State = acct.Account_ID == 0 
                                          ? EntityState.Added 
                                          : EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```